# Realizar un update de un array usando pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Quiero actualizar esta tabla con este *array*:

```
$datos[] = array('id_comprobantes' => $value['id_comprobantes'],
                    'estado' => "GENERADO");
```

Con esto lo envió al modelo:

```
$actu = $this->model->actualizar_est($datos);
```

Y al recibir intente con esto pero nada no me funciona.

```
public function actualizar_est($data)
    {

                foreach ($data as $clave => $valor) {


                    $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($valor));
                    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($valor));
                    $sth = $this->db->update('comprobantes',$fieldNames, "`id_comprobantes` = $fieldValues");

                    foreach ($valor as $key => $value) {
                        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
                    }
                    $sth->execute(); //Ejutamos el segunto Insert
                    if ($sth == true) {
                    $this->sms = "Actualizado";
                    }else{
                    $this->sms = "No se pudo actualizar el registro";
                    }
                }
        return $this->sms;
    }
```

Como podría lograr que se actualice correctamente.

Comment: Estas programando en algún Framework?

Comment: si es un framework MVC que encontre en github - nova framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo poco que puede encontrar en la documentación, el problema está en la estructura del array, no es necesario hacer los implodes y separar los nombres de los campos de su valor correspondiente y tampoco sería necesario execute(), dado que el update() se encarga de ejecutar la consulta. Te recomiendo que cuando vayas a usar un framework, procures usar uno que tenga documentación suficiente para que te puedas guiar, en ese orden de ideas, te propongo lo siguiente para solucionarlo:

La documentación indica el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$postdata = array(
    'firstName' => $firstName,
    'lastName'  => $lastName,                                 
    'email'     => $email                            
);

$where = array('contactID' => $id);

$this->model->updateContact($postdata, $where); 

public function updateContact($data, $where)
{
    $this->db->update(PREFIX.'contacts',$data, $where);
}
```

En ese caso, y considerando que cada array de data es un registro a actualizar (No se porque haces un insert) el código quedaría así:

```
public function actualizar_est($data)
{

    foreach ($data as $valor) {

        $where = array('id_comprobantes' => $valor['id_comprobantes']);
        $info = array('estado' => $valor['estado']);

        $sth = $this->db->update('comprobantes',$info, $where);

        if($sth == true){
            #Codigo...
        }else{
            #Codigo...
        }
    }
}
```

Pruébalo y me avisas si te funciona - en todo caso no tengo experiencia con el framework en cuestión